# Finding out if a one of several forms are open in MS Access

Tags: vba, ms-access, syntax

I need to iterate through a list of forms to see if they are open and then do something with them if they are. The following works:

```
Public Sub isloadedtester()
    Dim iForm As Variant
    
    For Each iForm In CurrentProject.AllForms
        Debug.Print iForm.name & ": " & CurrentProject.AllForms(iForm.name).IsLoaded
    Next
    
End Sub
```

but it loops through *all* forms. So I thought the following should work to loop through only the forms I care about:

```
Public Sub isloadedtester2()
    Dim iForm As Variant
    Dim list
    
    list = Array(Form_some, Form_another)
    
    For Each iForm In list
        Debug.Print iForm.name
        Debug.Print ".isloaded: " & CurrentProject.AllForms(iForm.name).IsLoaded
        Debug.Print "direct: " & SysCmd(acSysCmdGetObjectState, acForm, iForm.name)
        Debug.Print "by fn: " & IsLoaded(iForm.name)
    Next
    
End Sub
Public Function IsLoaded(FormName As String, Optional aType As AcObjectType = acForm)

    IsLoaded = (SysCmd(acSysCmdGetObjectState, aType, FormName) <> 0)

End Function
```

However, the second version always sees forms as loaded, no matter which of several ways to read loaded state I use:

```
.isloaded: True
direct: 1
by fn: True
```

It's almost like assigning a form to an array makes VBA load the form.

Should I use something other than an array for this? I realize I could do this as an array of names that I also loop through to see if one fits, but that seems awkward, so I first wanted to see if I am just doing something slightly different than it needs to be.

Comment: Try with the array of names, and also restart Access, just in case.

Answer (score 1):

If you only want open forms, then use the Forms collection. It includes only open forms

```
Dim intFrm As Integer
  If Forms.Count > 0 Then
  For intFrm = 0 To Forms.Count - 1
     'Debug.Print Forms(intFrm).NAME
      If Forms(intFrm).Name IsInYourList Then
        DoSomething
      End IF
  Next intFrm
End If
```

Comment: I want to do something to each of several forms, if open. So if I used the Forms collection, I would still need to iterate through each of the forms I want to work with and see if it is in Forms (or iterate through Forms to see if it's one of my forms). How would I do that, then?

Comment: Sorry, I wasn't clear. For a list of forms I give, I want to check if they are open, and if so, do something. Some of the forms on my list may not be open, and some of the open forms will not be on my list. So the it's an issue of comparing lists. Your new example still deals with one list only. It's when I put the forms in a list that Access seems to see them as open even if they are not actually open on the screen.

Comment: You say you only want to do something if the form is open. So, simply go through the open forms and check if an open form is on your list. Then do something with it. I've edited my answer.

Answer (score 0):

If you have a list of form names, you can do it the "old-fashioned" way with [`SysCmd`](https://learn.microsoft.com/en-us/office/vba/api/access.application.syscmd)

```
Public Function IsLoaded(FName As String, Optional aType As AcObjectType = acForm)

    IsLoaded = (SysCmd(acSysCmdGetObjectState, aType, FName) <> 0)

End Function
```

and

```
For Each iForm In list
    Debug.Print iForm.Name & ": " & IsLoaded(iForm.Name)
Next
```